# Gitlab: How to create a badge for the percent of jobs passing in latest pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab pipeline running regression tests on a project of ours. The pipeline runs a few jobs in the same stage. We usually have a few failures each night and I want a badge that will give me a percent of how many jobs are passing. It seems like [coverage reports and their badges](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-report-badge) are designed more for a single job, where I want a coverage report for multiple jobs based on how many jobs pass.

How would I go about this?  Is a coverage report the right path to investigate?